# Android : Watch video

Tags: android, video

How can I put in my activity a video from URL ? such ad new android market. It's possibile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this example code,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoPlayActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.video);
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    final MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this){
        /*public void hide()
        {
            mc.show();
        }*/
    });
   videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.androidbook.com/akc/filestorage/android/documentfiles/3389/movie.mp4"));
// videoView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/rabbit-and-snail.3gp");
   videoView.requestFocus();
   videoView.start();


}

}
```

in the above code place the URL of your video file which you want to play.

Answer (score 0):

can't you use Android VideoView? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html

not sure I understand your question fully.